# JS file works in all platforms except IPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

OK, so we found this issue where we have a Web app that has a main.js file.

So our index.html has

```
<script src="res/js-files/main.js"></script>
```

Now Ipad users where complaining about the web app not working as expected, so we reached to the conclution that main.js was not getting loaded. It's happening in Safari and also in Chrome for IPad

We passed the main.js through a compiler, and discovered that we had some code issues. In some parts, we had:

```
catch {
     ...    
}
```

In stead of

```
catch(e) {
    ...
}
```

The thing is that Windows PC's or Android systems did not have this problem; so I guess the iOS js compiler is somehow different and more strict.

Now even after correcting this issue, some IPads are working, but some are not yet loading the main.js. We're yet to confirm if it may bi caching issues, but anyway .. Is there any documentation about how different platforms' JS compilers work and things to have in mind before publishing cross-platofmr js web apps?

Comment: I assume we're talking about the iPad's Safari app?

Comment: Can you inspect the issue using Inspect Element on Desktop/Laptop. You can follow the steps : http://robandlauren.com/2013/09/14/test-on-devices/ . By doing this yuo will get errors (if any) at loading time.

Comment: Sorry, updated the question, it happens in Safari but also in chrome for Ipad